# Which MediaStore columns should i use to modify an audio file's meta data e.g song title , artist , album in android 11 Scoped storage

Tags: audio, metadata

I have a problem when it comes to modifying the meta data of audio files in my application , when using mediaStore and content Resolver , however modifying the audio's file display name is not a problem . Despite having the consent to modify the file via uri and reference (_ID) of the audio file I am unable to modify the tags .. The use of external libraries such as Jaudiotagger and mp3agic only provide me with (read-only) exceptions since these libraries use the fil's path to  read & modify . MediaStore.createDelete request works well on the other hand .. so my question is which columns are the right ones for edititng the meta data of anaudio file.

This is the documentation on mediaStore columns that I went through :
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns

Yes , I use mediaStore to access the audio files from my device . so i am able to read all audio files on my android 11

My application targets sdk 32

```
Manifest permission :
 <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
```

How i access the audio files :

```
`Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

String order = MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE+ " ASC";

String[] projection = new String[0];
projection = new String[]{
                   MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
                   MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                   MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
                   MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, // path
                   MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST ,
                   MediaStore.Audio.Media.YEAR ,
                   MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ARTIST, //requires android 11
                   MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                   MediaStore.Audio.Media.GENRE, //requires android 11
                   MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE
           };

            Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null,
                    null, ""+order);

            if(cursor !=null)
            {
                while(cursor.moveToNext())
                {
                    String album = cursor.getString(0);
                    String title = cursor.getString(1);
                    String duration = cursor.getString(2);
                    String path = cursor.getString(3);
                    String artist = cursor.getString(4);
                    String year = cursor.getString(5);
                    String album_artist = cursor.getString(6);
                    String id = cursor.getString(7);
                    String genre = cursor.getString(8);
                    String size = cursor.getString(9);
                    String fav_status = "0";
                    String playlist = "none";
                    String date_modified = "0";
                    String junction = "0";
```

My code to edit the audio meta data :

This is upon user granting permission to modify the audio file ...

```
uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI ,
                    Long.parseLong(key_id)) ;

 cv.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.IS_PENDING , 1);
            contentResolver.update(uri , cv, null , null);

            cv.clear();
          
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R){
                cv.put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME , title); <--- this actually gets updated!
                cv.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.GENRE , genre);
                cv.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE , title);
                cv.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.ARTIST, artist);
                cv.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.ALBUM , album);
                cv.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.YEAR , year);

            }
            cv.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA , String.valueOf(uriImage));
            cv.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.IS_PENDING , 0);
            contentResolver.update(uri , cv, " "+MediaStore.MediaColums._ID+"="+key_id+"" , null);
```

`
What is crazy is that i tried all the columns from MediaStore.Audio.Media ,  MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns but none of them actaully gets the audio meta data updated . so is there a correct column for this or not ?

please  feel free to ask , if you require additional information